# R: Integrating over a polygon

Tags: polygon, spatial, numerical-integration

I want to integrate over a polygon, I have been tryig with the polyCub.SV() function from the mvtnorm package:

```
#defining the covariate function:

elev.fn<-function(s){
  s<- matrix(s,ncol=2)
  (s[,1]+s[,2]-100)/40.8
}


mu <- function(s,beta0,beta1) exp(beta0+beta1*elev.fn(s=s))


polyCub.SV(Mypolygon,f=mu,beta0=beta0,beta1=beta1,nGQ=2,rotation=FALSE)
```

the result is NAN

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give an example of desired input and output of elev.fn

Comment: the input are all the points s inside a polygon and a covariate that represents some characteristic to the place (cov=elev.fn) and the output is the integral over the polygon with respect to s of the function exp(beta0+beta1*cov(s)): $\int_{polygon} (exp(beta0+beta1*cov(s)))ds$

Comment: I like sentences with punctuation marks and capital letters.

Comment: Please make your questions and examples reproducible. Make a script and run it in a fresh R session to test that it works and produces the error you claim. For instance I cannot see any function named `polyCub.SV()` in `mvtnorm` and I think it must be in `polyCub`? Errors like this are detected by writing a short script and running it in a fresh session with nothing loaded. Also, remember to follow up on questions you have posted and mark answers as accepted or explain what is missing if you want to motivate people to help you again.

Comment: `Mypolygon`, `beta0` and `beta1` are undefined. With `library(polyCub)`, `Mypolygon <- spatstat::letterR`, `beta0 <- 1` and `beta1 <- 2`, the code works for me (gives 0.09488869). BTW, your choice `nGQ=2` is rather low, but seems to be enough for my example polygon and parameter settings.